# Preciso de uma ferramenta de construção de parsers

Tags: parser, linguagens-formais

Então, primeiramente preciso de uma ferramenta de construção de parses, não sei exatamente o que é e onde acho, se possível de preferência na linguagem Python.

Eu vou utilizar essa ferramenta com o intuito de implementar um reconhecedor de expressões para um "parser descendente recursivo" que eu criei anteriormente.

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 2):

O que deseja é um gerador de *parser* e provavelmente o [ANTLR](https://www.antlr.org/) é o mais usado de todos. Não que ele seja certamente o melhor para o que precisa. [Coco/R](http://ssw.jku.at/Coco/) é outro bem usado. Mais um é o [SableCC](http://sablecc.org/). Alguns gostam do [JavaCC](https://javacc.org/). Ainda há quem prefira os antigos [YACC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yacc)/[Bison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Bison). Vale a pena dar uma olha no [GOLD](http://www.goldparser.org/). Nem todos geram código Python.

Para saber como faz o *parser* é só entrar em um curso com uma boa carga horária sobre o assunto, não dá para responder em uma resposta na internet, principalmente de forma exata.

Answer (score 0):

Para Python o meu favorito é o lark-parser https://github.com/lark-parser/lark
   (pip install lark-parser).