# Parser Generator e Transpilador qual a diferença?

Tags: terminologia, compiladores, teoria-da-computação

Enquanto estudava sobre tipos de compiladores me deparei com o termo: **Source-to-Source** que se refere ao processo de [transpilação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/189894/o-que-%C3%A9-transpila%C3%A7%C3%A3o).

Acontece que algumas seções mais a frente o termo **Parser-Generator** e alguns sinônimos como  **Compiler-Compiler**, **Compiler-Generator** surgiram definindo um mesmo conceito.

E aqui começou uma grande confusão, afinal Parser-Generator e Transpilador funcionam da mesma forma ou existe diferença ? Se existe diferença, qual é a diferença entre eles ?

Se possível deixe referencias pois sempre estou lendo, se possível também cite alguns parsers-generators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não falarei sobre transpilação porque já foi explicado na pergunta *linkada* e porque o assunto nada tem a ver com a outra dúvida, é como perguntar qual a diferença entre aço e fresadora, ambos são usados na produção de um carro, mas não possuem relação direta, e ainda, explicando o que é um gerador de *parser* isso ficará claro.

Os outros termos, na prática,  são mais ou menos sinônimos (pode ter alguma diferença sutil, algum fazer um pouco mais que outros) e indicam que você tem uma ferramenta que ajuda criar compiladores, especialmente a parte do *parser* dele, o que geralmente inclui o *lexer* também.

Um *parser* é algo trabalhoso e cansativo de fazer, além de ser fácil dar algum erro. è complicado ficar mexendo em código toda vez, e principalmente é chato fazer experimentação de gramática assim. Como o *parsers* é o código que expressa para o computador de como lidar com a gramática, se você tiver um padrão de como expressar a gramática de uma forma mais abstrata, mas como um humano pode entender você pode ter uma software que leia isso e crie o código do *parser* seguindo as regras da gramáticas expressadas anteriormente em uma linguagem de não programação (geralmente alguma varação de [BNF](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/178720/101)).

Então o gerador de *parser* costuma vir com uma ferramenta completa, um IDE para criar um compilador, um exemplo é o ANTLR, o mais conhecido:

[image: Screenshot do ANTLR]

Assim você pode testar, experimentar diversas formas de gramática, vai obtendo todas informações, vê oque dá errado, e quando está satisfeito e quer ver isso real manda gerar um código que será usado no compilador, é só nessa hora que o *parsers generator* entra, ele escreve o código para você para usar no compilador, assim você não precisa se preocupar com isso.

Em geral o código não é dos melhores, por isso em linguagens de alto perfil eles não são usados, ou seja, quem quer performance, mais poder e flexibilidade na linguagem ou gerar melhores mensagens de erro, não é uma boa ferramenta. Mas é bem útil onde você não pode gastar tempo demais com o compilador ou está só o prototipando.

O transpilador já é o compilador, por isso não dá para comparar, pode ser que um transpilador tenha sido gerado, em parte, por um gerador de *parser*.

Alguém poderia dizer que o gerador de parser é um transpilador, e aí não teria diferença, seria só uma forma diferente de classificar a mesma coisa, mas dá para contestar um pouco isso, estritamente é verdade, mas os objetivos são diferentes, caberia um debate, não aqui.

Deve interessar:

- [Devo usar um gerador de parser ou devo desenvolver meu próprio código para fazer "parse" e "lex"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2130/101)
- [Quais as principais vantagens e desvantagens de se usar um parser LL ou um LR?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2044/101)
- [Preciso de uma ferramenta de construção de parsers](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/385627/101)
- [Como é desenvolvida uma linguagem de programação?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/124436/101)

Comment: Excelente resposta, tirou muitas duvidas sobre o que eu achava sobre um parser... embora meu pensamento tenha partido dessa premissa: 

"Alguém poderia dizer que o gerador de parser é um transpilador, e aí não teria diferença, seria só uma forma diferente de classificar a mesma coisa, mas dá para contestar um pouco isso, estritamente é verdade, mas os objetivos são diferentes, caberia um debate, não aqui."; 

Mas uma vez, muito obrigado.